# Setting tool-specific parameters within the QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is it possible to set certain parameters of tools within set up models when opening a saved model (not edit, but double click and running)

I am talking about being able to set certain tool specific parameters such as distance in the "fixed distance buffer" tool as model parameters that then can be changed in the model window before running the model?

I treid to set up strings but the the tools withion the models don´t allow for triggering the string variables. So far only in- and output layers can be specified but not the input fields of desired tool-specific parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a number instead of a string. Double-click on the Number parameter and set your default distance (I called it "buffer distance" in the image below):

[image]

After you have done this, trigger it from the dialog of the tool:

[image]

Finally, save your model and you have done. You will able to directly set a different distance before running the model.

Comment: thanks a lot! You solved this problem for me. Do you know if it is also possible tto change the order of  parameters in the model?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! What do you mean with "changing the order of parameters"?

Comment: when opening the model (double click), the input field of the specified parameter is asked after the output location of the output. I would like to change the positions of these parameters

Comment: Sincerely I don't know if it is possible. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOiDX.png)is what I see when running my model and actually I'm curious to kwow why you see a different behavior...

Comment: maybe it has to do with the order I set the parameters when creating the model. The distance variable was the last one I specified. It´s not such a big deal. You helped me out. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you can't solve this, you may ask a new question to get more attention from other users of the community.